# I want to join user table with log table twice

Tags: sql

user table:

```
id = 1
name = David,
id= 2
name = Jhon
```

log table:

```
user_id = 1
guest_id = 2
```

wanted output

```
user_name = David
guest_name = Jhon
```

Comment: Join user table twice. Have different table aliases.

Comment: could you write the sql code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T.NAME,T2.NAME
FROM LOG_TABLE L
JOIN USER_TABLE T ON L.USER_ID=T.ID
JOIN USER_TABLE T2 ON L.guest_id =T2.ID
```

You can use something like this